# Accessing web method from other application getting 500 internal server error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to access web method which is in other asp.net application using below code from MVC 4 controller

```
using (WebClient client = new ReplicateUserControl())
{
    string url = "http://localhost:1469/CMSPages/WebService.asmx/AuthWebMethod";
    //List<string> getWidgetValue = new List<string>();
    System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection reqparm = new    
    System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
    reqparm.Add("Query", "changeTheme");
    var getValue  = client.UploadValues(url, "POST", reqparm);                   
}
```

and Below is my web method of other asp.net application which is created to load user control HTML data and setting it in one list string.

```
[WebMethod(MessageName = "AuthWebMethod")]
public byte [] AuthWebMethod(string Query)
{

    string getStringList = "";
    byte[] setValue;
    UserControl userControl;
    using (Page page = new Page())
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Query))
        {

            if (Query.ToUpper() == "USERINFO")
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
                HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);
                userControl = (UserControl)page.LoadControl(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/UserControls/Fortius.DreamTrips/UserInformation.ascx"));
                userControl.RenderControl(hw);

                getStringList += sb.ToString();


            }
            else if (Query.ToUpper() == "CHANGETHEME")
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
                HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);
                userControl = (UserControl)page.LoadControl(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/UserControls/Fortius.DreamTrips/DreamTrips_Themes.ascx"));
                userControl.RenderControl(hw);

                getStringList += sb.ToString();
            }


        }
    }

   setValue = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(getStringList);

    return setValue;
}
```

As we can see in this web method I am loading user control HTML and script and CSS in list string.

I am able to hit this method but when it returns there I am getting `500 Internal Server Error`.

Comment: Have you debugged the server side? Do the method gets hit and throw an exception during its execution or it doesn't even reach the method? Add a breakpoint on your webmethod first line and see what happens.

Comment: As you can see I have clearly mentioned "I am able to hit this method". now i convert this method from list string to byte array so i am able to get data in byte but when i am converting it is not converting properly.

Comment: Now the issue is in the above web method code snippet i am parsing string value in byte array so i checked the length of that but when i am parsing it in var or byte array object then the length of byte is changed and due to that it is not converting properly from byte to string.

Comment: try using `getStringList = sb.ToString()` instead of `getStringList += sb.ToString()`.`""` is a valid value for `string`.